# Raspberry PI 3 язык Си Вывод в консоль кириллических символов

Tags: c, кириллица, raspberry-pi

Raspberry PI 3. Операционная система локализована.
/etc/locale.gen раскомментировано:
ru_RU.CP1251 CP1251

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define RESET   "\033[0m"
#define YELLOW  "\033[1;33m"

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    
    printf("\033[%d;%dH%s%s%s",3,0,YELLOW, "Привет!!!\n",RESET);
    
}
```

Результат вот такой.

```
РџСЂРёРІРµС‚!!!


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

Как добиться вывода кириллических символов?

Comment: `$ echo "РџСЂРёРІРµС‚" | iconv -f utf-8 -t cp1251` → `Привет`. не надо в utf-ный мир тащить протухшие тридцать лет назад решения.

Comment: даже не так, не нужно в линукс мир тащить все виндовые костыли. setlocale тоже не нужно. Главное, что бы консоль была в utf8 (она по умолчанию уже такая, кроме некоторых хитрых, которые включают koi8) и исходники в таком же сохранить виде. и все.

Comment: Не совсем понял ответ???? текс программы написан в utf-8. Все вокруг по русски. Только в консоли вывода моей программы неверная кодировка. Я раскомментировал поочереди все три варианта, но результат тот же.

Comment: в /etc/locale.gen не должно быть расскоментировано ru_RU.CP1251 CP1251, кроме случае, если у Вас длинная борода с свитером слились в единое целое и Вы понимаете, что вы делаете.  Там должна быть расскоментирована строка `uk_UA.UTF-8 UTF-8` или подобная. Потом перегенерировать локали (locale-gen). С кода убрать setlocale и убедится, что он сохранен в utf-8. Все, профит.